# Creating Django Filter in a bootstrap dropdown based on the django-admin created categories

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I am 2 months into Python-Django and I do not have the full experience to carry on with my what I want to do.

I like to create a **Filter or a Dropdown Filter** such that anyone can choose from the **for-loop rendered categories in the dropdown** to filter or search by category. I managed to create a full search with Haystack with Whoosh (You can test my Haystack Search [here](http://myrioiapps.webfactional.com) and search with category called **marketing**)

Can someone shed more light on how I can filter my list based on categories looped in a dropdown? Am really confused.

**Here the code to my working Haystack Search**

**search_indexes.py**

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from haystack.query import EmptySearchQuerySet
from .models import Mentor
from .models import *


class MentorIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author1 = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='first_name')
    author2 = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='last_name')
    author3 = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='category')
    author4 = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='email')
    author5 = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='location')

    def get_model(self):
        return Mentor

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

**home.html**

```
<form method="get" action="/search/" class="navbar-form">
    <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
        <div class="input-group" style="display:table;">
            <input class="form-control" name="q" placeholder="Search Mentors Here. You can search by Location, Email, Name, e.t.c." autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">
            <span class="input-group-btn" style="width:1%;">
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                    <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
            </span>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**app url config** (**url.py**)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from mentoring_application.views import profile


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', profile, {}, name='mentor-profile'),
]
```

**project url config** (**url.py**)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from mentoring_application.views import HomeView, profile


admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view()),
    url(r'^mentor/', include('mentoring_application.urls', namespace='mentor')),
    url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls'))
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .models import *
from .models import Mentor
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404


# Create your views here.


class HomeView(View):
    # @staticmethod
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        mentors = Mentor.objects.all()
        return render(request, "mentoring_application/home.html", {"mentors": mentors})


def profile(request, pk, template='mentoring_application/profile.html'):
    mentor = get_object_or_404(Mentor, pk=pk)  # pk is primary key, so url will be site.com/profile/3
    context = {'mentor': mentor}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

For more clarity, this picture shows a category filter I like to do.

[image: the picture here]

Comment: What is the view method that sends the template data? Can you post that?

Comment: @TimS. am not sure I understand your question but I have made an update as requested. However, I will like to create a filter by category.

Comment: Normally how it works is that your view builds the object based on your filter criteria, then sends the filtered object/queryset to the template to be rendered as a drop down list. I haven't done this specifically before, but its the view's role to send the data to the template for rendering.

Comment: @TimS. robably write me a solution if you can.

Comment: I'm not in a position currently to write a whole solution, but a starting place would be to build a httprequest based on the filter criteria, then you can replace `mentor = get_object_or_404(Mentor, pk=pk)` with something that looks like `mentor = Class.objects.filter(fieldname=criteria)` and then send that to your view, which could be used to populate your dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In accordance to the comment given by @TimS and some other helps from another community, I wrote a solution to filter by category and it works.

Below is the hack that made its work:

**home.html**

This is the looped dropdown from categories table. I created a name element called `category-filter` for the selection of the categories on my template.

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
    <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right">
        <form method="get">
            <select id="men-filter-cat" class="form-control" name="category-filter" onchange="this.form.submit();">
                <option value="all">Filter by category</option>
                {% for c in categories %}
                    <option value="{{ c.category }}" {% if selected == c.category %}selected=selected"{% endif %}>
                        {{ c.category }}
                    </option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**views.py**

I redefined my HomeView to respond to the selected request with a variable called `chosen_filter` and my `views.py` becomes:

```
class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        mentors = Mentor.objects.all()
        chosen_filter = self.request.GET.get('category-filter')
        if chosen_filter:
            mentors = mentors.filter(category__category=chosen_filter)
        return render(request, "mentoring_application/home.html", {"mentors": mentors, 'selected': chosen_filter, 'categories': Category.objects.all().order_by('category')})


def profile(request, pk, template='mentoring_application/profile.html'):
    mentor = get_object_or_404(Mentor, pk=pk)  # pk is primary key, so url will be site.com/profile/3
    context = {'mentor': mentor}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

This is what worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: If you eventually didn't use dropdown, then you could use a list item in html to render your categories and define your html to submit onClick.